# How are feats determined for creatures with hit dice and class levels?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, character-advancement, character-levels, hit-dice

For a character with hit dice that is adding its first character level, does it get a feat at first character level or its next odd hit dice?

For example a bugbear becomes a bugbear barbarian 1.  Will it gain a feat?

Comment: I wonder if the Advanced Race Guide due out next year will provide more clarification?  I thought there was some discussion in the core about playing non-standard races (although not sure about races with extra HD)

Comment: @mirv120 There is, but it's pretty "loose" around races with HD.  Pretty easy for races without actually...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the D20 core, Monster HD are a class level.

Feats come from three sources: Every odd character level, class-specific feats (called Class Features), and sometimes a racial feat or two.

So, the class-specific fighter feat at level 1 is at CLASS level 1.

The feats in the monster description usually include racial and character level.

EG: A 4 HD Centaur is a 4th level character; make him a level 1 fighter, and he is now a 4HD centaur (with the racial feats), 1st level fighter (with the level 1 feats for that), and 5th level character (with the level 5 feats).

For a 3HD monster, he gets his ever odd character level feat when he gains 2 class levels. He gains his 1st level class-features at level in that class.

From what I recall from the beta, that hadn't changed.

Answer (score 2):

In Pathfinder, monster PCs have no special rules - they get all benefits of PC class levels including the usual feats per level.  The [PRD doesn't speak to this](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/monsters-as-pcs) (and old d20 stuff is never carried over without comment into Pathfinder) and note that [chargen software like PCGen](http://wiki.pcgen.org/Pathfinder_bonus_feat_progression) have implemented it this way.