# When monster cohorts level up, do they work just like a PC of that class level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

That is, if a monster cohort levels up with a PC and they would normally qualify for a class ability, like the fighter's **bravery** or a barbarian's **rage**, do the monster cohorts also get these abilities?

Do also get feats and skills just like a leveling character would or is the class leveling of monster cohorts mostly just for the sake of advancing their usual stats?

Comment: *Almost* a duplicate of [How are feats determined for creatures with hit dice and class levels?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8978/how-are-feats-determined-for-creatures-with-hit-dice-and-class-levels?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**When a Creature Gains Class Levels, It Gains the Class's Features**
After all, that's why it *takes* class levels. But while the creature may possess the class features, some individual creatures may find *using* such class features difficult (e.g. creatures without the capacity for speech who take levels in a spellcasting class need to find alternative methods of fulfilling the verbal components; creatures without hands struggle to use many weapons despite a class granting it proficiency).

**Monster Advancement's a Little Tricky**
Creatures with more than 1 Hit Die from these Hit Dice gain feats and skills. When the creature gains 1 level in a class, it adds another 1 Hit Die. A creature's Hit Dice equals its character level for determining its feats and maximum skill ranks. You can use this [table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/monster-creation#Table-Statistics-Summary) to help you determine, for instance, how many feats a creature with class levels has by adding the class levels to the creature's Hit Dice. For example, a [hill giant](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/giants/giant-true/giant-hill) has 10 Hit Dice. Were it to take 1 level of oracle, it would then have 11 HD and be eligible for another feat.